# Indexing pagefiles with EPiServer Find

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I'm trying to index page files with EPiServer Find (7.0.586.24), but the indexer doesn't seem to index documents in subdirectories in the page file folder. For instance I have a page with a page file folder like this:

```
MyPage
   |- Page files
   |- File1
   |- Directory
      |- File2
      |- File3
```

The logs reveal that the following exception is thrown:

```
2014-07-22 16:13:39,234 [25] ERROR EPiServer.Find.Cms.Module.IndexingModule: 
An exception occured while indexing (UnifiedFile). Unable to retrieve the page
reference for page file "File.pdf" in folder 
templates_project_phase_Acquisition. Executing with language branch: no. 
{log4net:HostName=THOMRAND} 
EPiServer.Find.Cms.ContentIndexerException: Unable to retrieve the page reference for 
page file "Overtidsliste.pdf" in folder templates_project_phase_Acquisition. Executing 
with language branch: no
    at EPiServer.Find.Cms.ContentIndexer.ShouldIndex(UnifiedFile file)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at EPiServer.Find.Cms.BaseIndexer.Index(IEnumerable`1 files, Int32 batchSize)
    at EPiServer.Find.Cms.Module.IndexingModule.IndexFileQueue()
```

My VirtualPathProvider is set to VirtualPathVersioningProvider. Is this related to a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but this might be the answer:

http://blog.nansen.com/2013/11/indexing-all-vpp-files-with-episerver-7.html